# how solve launching Talend open studio Errors?

Tags: talend

I have already installed the talend open studio for a month and suddenly when I open it last morning it gives this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.java.JavaProcessorUtilities.getTalendJavaProject(JavaProcessorUtilities.java:99)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.DefaultRunProcessService.getTalendProcessJavaProject(DefaultRunProcessService.java:514)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessService.getTalendProcessJavaProject(RunProcessService.java:356)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp$1.run(DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp.java:85)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp.earlyStartup(DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp.java:136)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp.startup(DeleteAllJobWhenStartUp.java:56)
>     at
>   org.talend.designer.runprocess.RunProcessService.deleteAllJobs(RunProcessService.java:228)
>     at org.talend.core.CoreService.deleteAllJobs(CoreService.java:318)
>     at
>   org.talend.core.repository.model.ProxyRepositoryFactory.logOnProject(ProxyRepositoryFactory.java:1879)
>     at
>   org.talend.repository.ui.login.LoginHelper$1.run(LoginHelper.java:426)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)

How can I deal with please...thanks?

Answer (score 1):

If you read logs (TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1\workspace.metadata.log), you can see

> Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException:
>   Could not read metadata for
>   'C:\Programmation\TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.root.indexes\properties.index'.
>   Unexpected version: 0.    at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:303)     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyBucket.load(PropertyBucket.java:258)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.Bucket.load(Bucket.java:274)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.BucketTree.loadBucketFor(BucketTree.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.properties.PropertyManager2.getProperty(PropertyManager2.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.getPersistentProperty(Resource.java:1205)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.loadVariablesAndContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3265)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.startup(JavaModelManager.java:5036)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.start(JavaCore.java:5651)  at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
>     ... 21 more

I just removed 'TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.root.indexes\properties.index' and it worked well

Answer (score -1):

- Go to folder `TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1\workspace.metadata.plugins`
- Delete metadata.plugin, and restart your system open talend studio. It will take some time for loading plugins+ metadata.
- After this we want to create talend projects.
- Go to windows + search -> type `run` -> type `%temp%`-> remove/ delete all files.